# image not displaying on canvas on first load of page

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, fabricjs

I am developing meme generator and I use fabricjs and canvas to do this. However on first load of page image is not copied to canvas, canvas is empty like this, or pressing ctrl+f5 in firefox :

Here is my code:

html:

```
<div class="col-centered" style="padding-top:15px;">
    <canvas id="canvas" width="{{$meme->width}}" height="{{$meme->height}}" style="border:0px solid white"></canvas>
</div>
```

javascript:

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');
canvas.selection = false;
canvas.renderAll();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After I tested your website, I found that, canvas is empty because it takes time to download image.

So when your JavaScript run these code, the image was still not downloaded.

```
canvas.add(imgInstance);
canvas.renderAll();
```

Try to use **fabric.Image.fromURL** instead and bind callback function on it may solve this.

```
var imgElement = document.getElementById('originalmeme');
var imgSource = imgElement.src;

fabric.Image.fromURL(imgSource, function(img) {
    img.set({top: 0, left: 0, angle: 0, opacity: 1, selectable: false});
    canvas.add(img);
});
```

Example on JSfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/7doq6gvh/1/

**Note:** Even using **fabric.Image.fromURL** it still take time to download image. It take me 6-8 seconds to download your image. Try to host image on other host may help this.

**Note2:** The reason image shown when you reload page is because the browser already cache image from the first load.

Comment: Hi i created this fiddle that uses image from my server and it works without a flaw: http://jsfiddle.net/yqu22unt/3/ Also I have the same problem with localhost images do not show if I press ctrl+f5 to load the page.

Comment: it seems that fromURL is working for me atleast on localhost haven't tested it yet on my server, however after I add image like canvas.add(img) and then later on add text with canvas.add(topText); canvas.add(bottomText); the text doesn't render it comes below the image, instead of top of the image, do you have an idea why is that? Would love to get fromURL solution working with text being displayed above.

Comment: actually your solution works perfectly and I solved the text problem with canvas.insertAt(img,0); Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

That's a good solution with fabric.js but it is easier with `window.onload = function () {<your canvas script> }`

Answer (score 1):

Suggesting you to work on image.onload();

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvasId');
img.onload = function () {
                canvas.setHeight(Height);
                canvas.setWidth(Width);
                canvas.setBackgroundImage("img path", canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas));
            };
```